# I want to make a custom bool which have all the properties like bool but default value should be "true" instead of "false"

Tags: swift

```
enum MyBool {
    case myTrue, myFalse
}

/// A value type whose instances are either `true` or `false`.

extension MyBool {
    /// Default-initialize Boolean value to `true`.

    init(){ self = .myTrue }
}

extension MyBool : BooleanLiteralConvertible {
    static func convertFromBooleanLiteral( value: Bool) -> MyBool {
        return value ? myTrue : myFalse
    }
}

extension MyBool : BooleanType {
    var boolValue: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .myTrue: return true
        case .myFalse: return false
        }
    }
}
extension MyBool {
    // MyBool can be constructed from BooleanType
    init(_ v : BooleanType) {
        if v.boolValue {
            self = .myTrue
        } else {
            self = .myFalse
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is mybool does not conform protocol BooleanLiteralConvertible.
Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Kartik, could you please explain why you're trying to do this? This seems very counter-productive... Also, I don't believe Bool has any default value in Swift specifically.

Comment: In Swift the `Bool` type doesn't have a default value anyway.

Comment: convertFromBooleanLiteral was used in very early Swift versions. Lookup the current definition of BooleanLiteralConvertible.

Comment: @vadian: Actually it has (in a sense).  `let b = Bool()` initializes `b` to `false`.

Comment: What's the use case of this? Wouldn't your code be a whole lot more readable if you just initialised your properties with `true` – rather than making some custom `BooleanType`? `true` is 4 characters long, whereas `MyBool()` is 8 characters long... so you're not exactly making your code any shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Conforming to `BooleanLiteralConvertible` requires the addition of an initializer which accepts `BooleanLiteralType` aka `Bool`. A slightly modified version of your example that conforms to `BooleanLiteralConvertible` and `BooleanType`:

```
enum MyBool: BooleanLiteralConvertible, BooleanType {
    case myTrue
    case myFalse

    var boolValue: Bool {
        return self == .myTrue
    }

    init() {
        self = .myTrue
    }

    init(booleanLiteral value: Bool) {
        self = value ? .myTrue : .myFalse
    }
}
```